# Hide Column in Newform.aspx SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, csom

How can I remove the "title" field in the process of installing a new list with JSOM?

I'm on Sharepoint 2013 online.

My code:

```
var field1 = newList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(
    "<Field Type='UserMulti' DisplayName='Name' Description='c' Required='FALSE' ShowField='NameWithPictureAndDetails' Name='Name'  Mult='FALSE' UserSelectionMode='PeopleAndGroups' />", true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addFieldInternalNameHint);

currentContext.load(field1);
currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
}

function onListCreationSuccess() {

var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle("AnstalldDatum");

    var fieldToEdit = list.get_fields().getByTitle("Title");
    fieldToEdit.setShowInDisplayForm(false);
    fieldToEdit.setShowInNewForm(false);
    fieldToEdit.setShowInEditForm(false);
    fieldToEdit.set_hidden(true);
    fieldToEdit.update();

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        console.log("Sucess: Fields installed! ");
        $(".status").append('List Installed');

     });
}
```

Comment: I was wondering, you don't want to hide it by using the list settings?

Comment: You cant hide it in the list settings

Comment: The example you have provided, this is the correct way of controlling the visibility of fields. Could you please specify what is not working?

Comment: List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Enable Content Types. Then, click on "Item" back in List Settings. There you can decide which fields to show on the forms. @Peter

Comment: Yes, but can i do that programmatically?

Comment: I can see my field "Title" in my display form

Answer (score 3):

The following methods allows to control field visibility in List Forms:

- [SP.Field.setShowInDisplayForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850877(v=office.15).aspx) - Sets the value of the
  `ShowInDisplayForm` property for this field
- [SP.Field.setShowInEditForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850856(v=office.15).aspx) - Sets the value of the
  `ShowInEditForm` property for this field
- [SP.Field.setShowInNewForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj838353(v=office.15).aspx) - Sets the value of the
  `ShowInNewForm` property for this field

The below example demonstrates how to set field visibility in `List Forms` using JSOM:

```
function setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldName,properties,success,failure)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var web = ctx.get_web(); 
     var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
     var field = list.get_fields().getByTitle(fieldName);
     field.setShowInDisplayForm(properties.ShowInDisplayForm);
     field.setShowInNewForm(properties.ShowInNewForm);
     field.setShowInEditForm(properties.ShowInEditForm);
     field.set_hidden(properties.Hidden);
     field.update();
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,failure);
}
```

**Usage**

Hide `Title` field from New Form page:

```
var listTitle = 'Custom List';
var fieldName = 'Title';


var properties = {
      'ShowInDisplayForm': true,
      'ShowInNewForm': false,
      'ShowInEditForm': true,
      'Hidden': false
};
setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldName,properties,
   function () {
      console.log("Field visibility settings has been changed");
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Its working for text field. but it give error "The node to be inserted is from a different document context." for choice field hide on edit and view form.

Comment: I notice that you're hiding the field at the list level but what if you want to set the field hidden at the content type level, would it still be the same approach? I'm trying to hide fields for a specific content type.